# Getting INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR for the specific token

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am having `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`  for the specific tokens. I am sharing one of them.

`Error rate` is 0.2%. I mean one of the 500 push notification sends `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`

**Problematic token** : `fLuRkjzsLWg:APA91bEwXR92vHerW-42dzs9GXYaVtHxBsvO9n8kuGy0_E3EGVTPszblq2-On3D83N8BJZzfViBpZaNVQN02G3x9YZc6o3R38z8E9CNVrGw639mT-D22ofUI88mcUZxukmrk0wIUCG1H`

```
[bipdev@agb01 application]$ grep M89sKidL-26 APPLICATION.log.2015-11-23-23
[DEBUG]-2015-11-23 23:37:27,801 ApplicationLogger: param:ServerReqOfflinePnBean [badge=4, ostype=A, pntoken=fLuRkjzsLWg:APA91bEwXR92vHerW-42dzs9GXYaVtHxBsvO9n8kuGy0_E3EGVTPszblq2-On3D83N8BJZzfViBpZaNVQN02G3x9YZc6o3R38z8E9CNVrGw639mT-D22ofUI88mcUZxukmrk0wIUCG1H, voippntoken=null, msgtype=T, jid=905366955282, groupname=null, filename=null, notificationtype=M, playSound=true, certtype=, callid=null, text=XXX, sender=xxxxx, receiver=9053130xxxxx, txnid=M89sKidL-26, service=false, osversion=4.3, appversion=3.1.5, serviceId=null]
[DEBUG]-2015-11-23 23:37:27,855 ApplicationLogger: Received: <message><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{&quot;message_type&quot;:&quot;nack&quot;,&quot;from&quot;:&quot;fLuRkjzsLWg:APA91bEwXR92vHerW-42dzs9GXYaVtHxBsvO9n8kuGy0_E3EGVTPszblq2-On3D83N8BJZzfViBpZaNVQN02G3x9YZc6o3R38z8E9CNVrGw639mT-D22ofUI88mcUZxukmrk0wIUCG1H&quot;,&quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;M89sKidL-26&quot;,&quot;error&quot;:&quot;INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR&quot;,&quot;error_description&quot;:&quot;&quot;}</gcm></message>
[INFO ]-2015-11-23 23:37:27,855 ApplicationLogger: handleNackReceipt() All:{"error":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","message_id":"M89sKidL-26","from":"fLuRkjzsLWg:APA91bEwXR92vHerW-42dzs9GXYaVtHxBsvO9n8kuGy0_E3EGVTPszblq2-On3D83N8BJZzfViBpZaNVQN02G3x9YZc6o3R38z8E9CNVrGw639mT-D22ofUI88mcUZxukmrk0wIUCG1H","error_description":"","message_type":"nack"}
[bipdev@agb01 application]$ 
[bipdev@agb01 application]$ 
[bipdev@agb01 application]$ grep uQxP6-149 APPLICATION.log.2015-11-23-22
[DEBUG]-2015-11-23 22:54:17,322 ApplicationLogger: param:ServerReqOfflinePnBean [badge=1, ostype=A, pntoken=fLuRkjzsLWg:APA91bEwXR92vHerW-42dzs9GXYaVtHxBsvO9n8kuGy0_E3EGVTPszblq2-On3D83N8BJZzfViBpZaNVQN02G3x9YZc6o3R38z8E9CNVrGw639mT-D22ofUI88mcUZxukmrk0wIUCG1H, voippntoken=null, msgtype=T, jid=905385524706, groupname=null, filename=null, notificationtype=M, playSound=true, certtype=, callid=null, text=XXX, sender=xxx, receiver=9053130xxxxx, txnid=uQxP6-149, service=false, osversion=4.3, appversion=3.1.5, serviceId=null]
[DEBUG]-2015-11-23 22:54:17,376 ApplicationLogger: Received: <message><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{&quot;message_type&quot;:&quot;nack&quot;,&quot;from&quot;:&quot;fLuRkjzsLWg:APA91bEwXR92vHerW-42dzs9GXYaVtHxBsvO9n8kuGy0_E3EGVTPszblq2-On3D83N8BJZzfViBpZaNVQN02G3x9YZc6o3R38z8E9CNVrGw639mT-D22ofUI88mcUZxukmrk0wIUCG1H&quot;,&quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;uQxP6-149&quot;,&quot;error&quot;:&quot;INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR&quot;,&quot;error_description&quot;:&quot;&quot;}</gcm></message>
[INFO ]-2015-11-23 22:54:17,376 ApplicationLogger: handleNackReceipt() All:{"error":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","message_id":"uQxP6-149","from":"fLuRkjzsLWg:APA91bEwXR92vHerW-42dzs9GXYaVtHxBsvO9n8kuGy0_E3EGVTPszblq2-On3D83N8BJZzfViBpZaNVQN02G3x9YZc6o3R38z8E9CNVrGw639mT-D22ofUI88mcUZxukmrk0wIUCG1H","error_description":"","message_type":"nack"}
[bipdev@agb01 application]$ 
[bipdev@agb01 application]$ 
[bipdev@agb01 application]$ 
[bipdev@agb01 application]$ grep 2q0X3-60596  APPLICATION.log.2015-11-23-22
[DEBUG]-2015-11-23 22:30:45,936 ApplicationLogger: param:ServerReqOfflinePnBean [badge=1, ostype=A, pntoken=fLuRkjzsLWg:APA91bEwXR92vHerW-42dzs9GXYaVtHxBsvO9n8kuGy0_E3EGVTPszblq2-On3D83N8BJZzfViBpZaNVQN02G3x9YZc6o3R38z8E9CNVrGw639mT-D22ofUI88mcUZxukmrk0wIUCG1H, voippntoken=null, msgtype=IC, jid=905385524706, groupname=null, filename=null, notificationtype=C, playSound=true, certtype=, callid=yZhN9vyXrl, text=XXX, sender=xxxx, receiver=9053130xxxxx, txnid=2q0X3-60596, service=false, osversion=4.3, appversion=3.1.5, serviceId=null]
[DEBUG]-2015-11-23 22:30:45,990 ApplicationLogger: Received: <message><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{&quot;message_type&quot;:&quot;nack&quot;,&quot;from&quot;:&quot;fLuRkjzsLWg:APA91bEwXR92vHerW-42dzs9GXYaVtHxBsvO9n8kuGy0_E3EGVTPszblq2-On3D83N8BJZzfViBpZaNVQN02G3x9YZc6o3R38z8E9CNVrGw639mT-D22ofUI88mcUZxukmrk0wIUCG1H&quot;,&quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;2q0X3-60596&quot;,&quot;error&quot;:&quot;INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR&quot;,&quot;error_description&quot;:&quot;&quot;}</gcm></message>
[INFO ]-2015-11-23 22:30:45,990 ApplicationLogger: handleNackReceipt() All:{"error":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","message_id":"2q0X3-60596","from":"fLuRkjzsLWg:APA91bEwXR92vHerW-42dzs9GXYaVtHxBsvO9n8kuGy0_E3EGVTPszblq2-On3D83N8BJZzfViBpZaNVQN02G3x9YZc6o3R38z8E9CNVrGw639mT-D22ofUI88mcUZxukmrk0wIUCG1H","error_description":"","message_type":"nack"}
```

Google describe the error in the link. but some thing is missing I think.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#table4

Internal Server Error   INTERNAL_SERVER_ 
ERROR   The server encountered an error while trying to process the request. You could retry the same request following the requirements listed in "Timeout" (see row above). If the error persists, please report the problem in the android-gcm group.

Comment: is google providing any option for validating token ?

Comment: Invalid tokens should just be deleted, it can be expired, user uninstalled app...

Comment: If so GCM has to send BAD_REGISTRATION or DEVICE_UNREGISTERED error that I am also handling these errors. But I cannot get any response for these tokens

Comment: If it returns Internal server error only for some tokens, clearly the tokens are bad, i will not bother about why they are i will just delete it.

Comment: many tokens also having internal_server_error, but when I retry to send same message, everything is fine. So I cannot remove all tokens having this error.

Comment: You can try to report the problem in the android-gcm group and resend the messages. I think it a temp connecting issue.